# Newly Created Block class not found in magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

In Magento 1.9.2.4, I am not able to create new block. When I create a class file and on frontend when I try to get the class name or get the layout, it says 'class not found'.

Existing blocks are working properly and only new one are not working.

I have defined block in config xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Custom_Homepage>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Custom_Homepage>
  </modules>
  <global>
    <blocks>
      <homepage>
        <class>Custom_Homepage_Block</class>
      </homepage>
    </blocks>
  </global>
</config>

<?php
 class Custom_Homepage_Block_Product_Slider3 extends
       Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List{
   protected function _construct(){
      echo 1212;exit;
   }
 }
 ?>
```

And trying to call block in template file:

```
$this->getLayout()->createBlock('homepage/product_Slider3')
->setTemplate('homepage/catalog/product/category-3.phtml')->toHtml();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try extend with Mage_Core_Block_Template instead of Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List. Also change this

```
$this->getLayout()->createBlock('homepage/product_Slider3') ->setTemplate('homepage/catalog/product/category-3.phtml')->‌​toHtml();
```

to

```
$this->getLayout()->createBlock('homepage/product_slider3') ->setTemplate('homepage/catalog/product/category-3.phtml')->‌​toHtml();
```

To display this block content, you can also call like this since you are not using any frontend layout

```
$this->getLayout()->createBlock('homepage/product_slider3');
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the typo in the block name that Jickson has mentioned- You should never create the block programmatically within a template. Instead, use Layout XML to add your block in to the block you need to call it from. Then, use `$this->getChildHtml()` within that block's template file to call your new block.

Creating it manually is essentially bypassing the framework, which defeats the purpose of using it.